# Checking same if condition to series of functions

Tags: c++

lets say for example i have the following code:

```
bool foo1() {
    check something...
}

void foo2() {
    do something ...
}
void foo3() {
    do something ...
}
void foo4() {
    do something ...
}
void foo5() {
    do something ...
}
void foo6() {
    if (foo1()) foo2();
    if (foo1()) foo3();
    if (foo1()) foo4();
    if (foo1()) foo5();
}
```

is there a better way to do this? i don't want to write the if statement every time, but each of the other functions might change the calculation of foo1().

i have a series of different functions and i want it to use foo1() before every call.

Comment: Perhaps the other functions can return a `bool` indicating that they "changed the calculation of foo1()". Then your foo6() can call `foo1()`, save its result in a `bool`, and call it again only if any of the other functions return a flag saying that they changed the return value of `foo1()`.

Comment: can you put a working example of your code?

Comment: Do `foo2` through `foo5` have identical declarations?

Comment: You can do some tricks to hide the evaluation of foo1(), but, frankly, your current code expresses its intent clearly, which should be your primary goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the functions in a container and then use a loop:

```
std::vector<void (*)()> functions = {foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5};
for (auto f: functions)
    if (foo1())
        f();
```